# My header is partially hiding the below content

Tags: html, css

I have a `header` fixed on top of my page. The content of my page is long so vertical scrollbars apprears. Below my header, the first text Inside my `container` isn't totally visible (partially hided by the fixed header).

How to fix it?

Thanks.

```css
header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  
}
```

```html
<header>
Hello, I am the header
</header>
<div class="container">
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
</div>
```

Comment: add a `margin-top` to your `.container` equal to that of the size of your header

Comment: This is normal behaviour, simply add a margin top to your container.

Answer (score 1):

Since your header is `fixed`, it will be placed "above" the viewport, outside of the document flow.

The `margin-top` on your `.container` will do nothing, because the margin has nothing 'to bounce on'. Instead, use a padding on your body.

```
body {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8egwezk/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your header is out the flow.

You must add a `padding-top` to your content equal to the height of your header.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you a fixed, or absolute element is gripped out of the DOM FLOW -> elements which are positioned absolute or fixed are also always positioned ABOVE elements that are static or block.

If you want to avoid that , give your div a padding.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/v2rjuw51/
here it is the fix. You can try with margin-top to the content or try to change from position fixed to relative

```
header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
    left:0;
  width: 100%;
    height:20px;
}
.container {
  margin-top:100px;
}

<header>
Hello, I am the header
</header>
<div class="container">
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
  Hello I am the content of the page <br/>  
</div>
```